# Remove space after if/for statement - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, format

So I just discovered the amazing use of Ctrl+Shift+F to format my code after nearly three years of using Eclipse and am wondering if I can change it to remove the space after formatting an if/for statement as such:

From this:

```
if (i == 1) {
    //do something else
} else {
    //do something
}
```

To this:

```
if(i == 1) {
    //do something else
}
else {
    //do something
}
```

I looked all over the Eclipse format area and saw nothing to edit this.

Comment: Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit... > White Space > Control statements > 'if else' > before opening parenthesis

Comment: You need to make a new profile in Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter.  Base it on one of the built-in ones, then edit the settings you need to.